# jinja match string after specific variables in json

Tags: json, ansible, jinja2

I am trying to let jinja check json file then get the output or do some action, I can do exactly the same but with yaml format, don't know what is happening with json

```html
{
  "failed": false,
  "changed": false,
  "stdout_lines": [
    {
      "vrfs": {
        "default": {
          "instList": {
            "1": {
              "ospfNeighborEntries": [
                {
                  "inactivity": 1547099204.137163,
                  "priority": 1,
                  "drState": "DR",
                  "routerId": "1.1.1.2",
                  "interfaceName": "Ethernet2",
                  "adjacencyState": "full",
                  "interfaceAddress": "1.1.1.2",
                  "options": {
                    "multitopologyCapability": false,
                    "doNotUseInRouteCalc": false,
                    "demandCircuitsSupport": false,
                    "nssaCapability": false,
                    "externalRoutingCapability": true,
                    "opaqueLsaSupport": false,
                    "linkLocalSignaling": false,
                    "multicastCapability": false
                  },
                  "details": {
                    "grLastRestartTime": null,
                    "backupDesignatedRouter": "1.1.1.1",
                    "areaId": "0.0.0.0",
                    "grHelperTimer": null,
                    "bfdRequestSent": false,
                    "numberOfStateChanges": 7,
                    "inactivityDefers": 0,
                    "bfdState": "adminDown",
                    "stateTime": 1547098942.137163,
                    "retransmissionCount": 0,
                    "designatedRouter": "1.1.1.2",
                    "grNumAttempts": 0
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "stdout": [
    {
      "vrfs": {
        "default": {
          "instList": {
            "1": {
              "ospfNeighborEntries": [
                {
                  "inactivity": 1547099204.137163,
                  "priority": 1,
                  "drState": "DR",
                  "routerId": "1.1.1.2",
                  "interfaceName": "Ethernet2",
                  "adjacencyState": "full",
                  "interfaceAddress": "1.1.1.2",
                  "options": {
                    "multitopologyCapability": false,
                    "doNotUseInRouteCalc": false,
                    "demandCircuitsSupport": false,
                    "nssaCapability": false,
                    "externalRoutingCapability": true,
                    "opaqueLsaSupport": false,
                    "linkLocalSignaling": false,
                    "multicastCapability": false
                  },
                  "details": {
                    "grLastRestartTime": null,
                    "backupDesignatedRouter": "1.1.1.1",
                    "areaId": "0.0.0.0",
                    "grHelperTimer": null,
                    "bfdRequestSent": false,
                    "numberOfStateChanges": 7,
                    "inactivityDefers": 0,
                    "bfdState": "adminDown",
                    "stateTime": 1547098942.137163,
                    "retransmissionCount": 0,
                    "designatedRouter": "1.1.1.2",
                    "grNumAttempts": 0
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Jinja template

```html
InterfaceName:  "{{ ospfresult.stdout[0]['vrfs']['default']['instList']['1']['ospfNeighborEntries']['interfaceName'] }}"
```

expected result

```
InterfaceName: Ethernet2
```

error received

```html
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'list object' has no attribute 'interfaceName'"}
        to retry, use: --limit @/etc/ansible/vxlan-arista/arista-test/testfacts.retry
```

Could you please help me how to solve this issue, I am using ansible 2.5.4

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Element in the list is missing

```
... ['ospfNeighborEntries'][0]['interfaceName']
```